# How to join multiple columns as one SQLite3

Tags: sqlite

I have a table that has two columns.

### id|custom_id

### 1 |9123

### 2 |null

### null|null

I want to output it like:

### id

### 1

### 2

### 9123

I tried `SELECT id FROM table UNION SELECT custom_id FROM table` and it works fine, but the output contains an empty line which is because of null values. If use `WHERE id IS NOT null` as condition on each `SELECT` query it works. Is there any other way to achieve the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

This is not more efficient than using a `WHERE column is not null` and it rejects duplicates from each column:

```
SELECT id FROM table group by id having max(id) = id
UNION ALL
SELECT custom_id FROM table group by custom_id having max(custom_id) = custom_id
```